# PHP Cannot echo out a function with a string before it

Tags: php, function, return, echo

I have made a function to echo my URL's, and this function works fine. But now I want to echo out this function with a string around it, but I get a wrong result.

The function `wzd_url()` uses a array with some data to build the url.

```
// Function for my URL's
function wzd_url($page) {
    global $wzd_pages;
    return bloginfo('wpurl') . '/' . $wzd_pages[$page][1];
}
```

Want to do for this for example:

```
echo 'test' . wzd_url(2);
```

And my result is:
http://www.website.com**test**/the-url-page-from-my-array

So it puts the string between it.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bloginfo('wpurl')** will echo the value. you need to use **get_bloginfo('wpurl')** which will return it.